# Use gnome-terminal in codelite instead of default terminal

Tags: setting, codelite

I'm trying to get gnome-terminal to work in codelite under

setting > preferences > terminal

I tried

```
gnome-terminal -x '$(CMD)'
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Failed to execute child process "/bin/sh -f /usr/lib/codelite/codelite_exec ./program" (No such file or directory)
```

I'm running Linux Mint 18.

---

Solution is to run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

from a terminal and select

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
```

as default terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeLite uses `x-terminal-emulator`. So as long as you define `x-terminal-emulator` to point to the correct terminal it will work.

See [this post](https://forums.codelite.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3482&p=15558) for more information

Comment: Link does not work

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem after upgrading to CodeLite 10.0 from the [CodeLite repository](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories). The problem occurs because CodeLite is now installing things in different directories - namely `codelite_xterm` and `codelite_exec`, which are now installed to `/usr/bin/`.

For me, on Ubuntu 16.10, I found the easiest solution was to change `Settings > Preferences > Terminal` to:

```
/usr/bin/codelite_xterm '$(TITLE)' '$(CMD)'
```

You can then run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

to select the terminal you wish to use (the default on Ubuntu 16.10 is gnome-terminal, so you won't have to run the last command if you're happy with gnome-terminal).